# ASP.NET Profile Properties returning another users results

Tags: asp.net, profile

I am using ASP.NET profile properties in .NET framework 2.0 application.

**Hosting**: On Amanzon server 
Operating System: Windows Server 2012
Sql Server : 2012
IIS: 8.5

Profile Properties are **anonymous** users

What is happening with the end users (not able to replicate myself) that the end users are seeing the profile properties of another user

**Example** Say i have country USA set in my profile property
Next time i visit the webpage it may show some another Country which may be set by another user.

In IIS currently **User Mode caching and Kerner Mode Caching enable.**

**Additionally:**
*I recently change the hosting means moved to another server so is that anything to do
with properties of anonymous users or do i need to clean all of the current profile users
data which i am scare of*

Code:

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="ActionRemember" allowAnonymous="true" />
    <add name="ActionName" allowAnonymous="true" />
     /// huge list of properties .......
  </properties>
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSql2005Server" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Open to give you more details..

**Update:** I disabled Kernel Caching for the aspx page and the error still persists

Comment: What does your `anonymousIdentification` section look like within your web.config.

Comment: Did you get a new IP address with the new server?  How many users are we talking about here?

Comment: @Paddy   <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />

Comment: @Paddy I am not sure about how may users are there but the site is popular a sort of blog site for general public awareness

Comment: You say that you 'login again'.  How does the login work if users are anonymous?

Comment: Means not logon means next time i visit the website

Comment: So on the same machine, probably with the same session cookies set, when you visit the site again, you get the profile of the previous user, is that correct?

Comment: Are you using a static variables to display the user information?

Answer (score -1):

Static variables retain their values across user sessions.

You will run in concurrency issues as more than one thread servicing a request can modify the value of the variable.

> What happens if there are 2 users simultaneously logged in from two
>   computers, User 1 sets the value as 100, then User 2 sets the value as
>   200. after that user 1 invokes the Get Value button.

What will he see as the value?
The user will see 200 afterwards.

I added a link for additional information [here](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2009/01/static-variables-and-their-implications.html)